# XCRUD buttons are not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, crud

I am using xcrud for my project. The code is below.

```
require('../xcrud/xcrud.php'); 
$xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance();
$xcrud->table('groups');
echo $xcrud->render();
```

It renders in a beautiful way. but 'add', 'edit' and other buttons are not working. The configuration files are ok.

I am working with LTE ADMIN bootstrap template. May be it is a cause of jquery conflict. Please help me.

Comment: Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

check your database.

For these buttons you must have a PRIMARY KEY or unique and better if its AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 0):

If you already add jquery files to page, you should disable xcrud's jquery from xcrud_config.php.

In line 41:

```
public static $load_jquery = false; // loads jQuery, turn it off if you already have jQuery on your page. jQuery version must be at least 1.7. If your jQuery loads in the bottom of page, you must activate $manual_load and use  Xcrud::load_css() & Xcrud::load_js() on your page.
public static $load_jquery_ui = true; // jQueryUI, turn it on if you already have jQueryUI on your page (datepicker and slider widgets are mandatory).
```